# Escape backslash in Ansible while posting json to teams webhook using uri module

Tags: ansible, jinja2, uri, microsoft-teams, webhooks

I have a file  called test.log where it contains a structure like below:

{"Check something" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Found something -

Name Path
test C:\Windows\system32\xyz"}

While reading the file using lookup, the backslash is already escaped(\).

{"Check something" : "Pass" , "Result" : "Found something -

Name Path
test C:\\Windows\\system32\\xyz"}

But when it is used to post this structure to teams using URI module, backslash is not being escaped and it is causing a bad payload format while posting and fails. How to escape backslash and post the structure to teams.

```
- uri:
    url: "{{webhook_url}}"
    method: POST
    body: "{'title': '{{title}}', 'text': '{{lookup(\"file\",\"{{filepath}}\") | replace (\"\'\",\"\\\'\") | replace (\"\\n\",\"   \\n\")}}'}"
    body_format: json
```

Error received in uri module is
"content": "Bad payload received by generic incoming webhook"

Also, the backslash issue happens only when I use the replace function after reading the file. If I'm not using replace then the backslash is automatically escaped and doesn't cause any issues.

Comment: Replace all of your filters with `to_json`.  See whether that works before trying anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this:

```
- uri:
    url: "{{webhook_url}}"
    method: POST
    body: "{{ { 'title': title , 'text': text } | to_json }}"
    body_format: json
  vars:
    text: "{{lookup('file', filepath) }}"
```

It's easier to use a `vars` block than to embed all that stuff.

Comment: Thanks! to_json solved the issue which I was facing.